# Lazy loading not working with Specification

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have migrated to spring v2.1.2.RELEASE and using hibernate version 5.3.7.FINAL

We have @OneToOne bi directional relationship between entity as follows

```
class Parent{

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", optional = false)
    @NotAudited
    private Child child; 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}

class Child{
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @MapsId
    @NotNull
    private Parent parent;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "indent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer parentId;

}
```

calling

```
parentRepository.findByIdIn(Collections.singletonList(1));
```

makes db call as:
Hibernate:

```
select parent0_.id as id1_19_ from  parent parent0_ where parent0_.id in (?)
```

Which is working fine, now consider use case,

```
public class Filter implements Specification<Parent> {

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Indent> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<Integer> parentIdList = new ArrayList<>();
            parentIdList.add(1);
            ArrayList<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            predicates.add(root.get("id").in(parentIdList));
            return predicates.size() == 0 ? null
                    : criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

        }

    } 



    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page - 1, pageSize, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
    Filter filter = new Filter();
    Page<Indent> indentPage = indentRepository.findAll(filter, pageRequest);
```

makes DB call to Child entity as well

```
Hibernate:
select parent0_.id as id1_19_ from  parent parent0_ where parent0_.id in (?)
select child0_.parent_id as parent_i1_29_ from child child0_ where child0_.indent_id in (?)
```

Is there any way to avoid Db call to child entity here?

Comment: The issue was with hibernate version I mentioned and fixed in 5.4
compile group: ‘org.hibernate’, name: ‘hibernate-core’, version: ‘5.4.0.Final’

Answer (score 1):

You can define an entity graph to specify a pattern that can be passed to a query to determine which attributes you want to be fetched. Attributes that are not included in the graph will be treated as LAZY by persistence provider.

```
    @Entity
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "only_id", attributeNodes={@NamedAttributeNode("id")})
    class Parent{
    
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", optional = false)
        @NotAudited
        private Child child; 
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;
    }
```

JPA API:

```
EntityGraph entityGraph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("only_idh");
// define your query
query.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph",graph);
```

More details : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs002.htm

With Spring Data JPA

```
 public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Integer> {
 
    @EntityGraph(value = "only id")
    Parent findById(Integer id)
```

More details : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph

JpaSpecificationExecutor :

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<Parent> {
   @Override
   @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"only_id"}, type=EntityGraphType.FETCH)
   Parent findByOne(Specification<Parent> spec);
}
```

More details : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html

Comment: In the above question, with named method query child entity is lazy loaded but when filter is used child entity is eagerly loaded, How can I achieve lazy loading of child entity with specification?

Comment: @atul Please see updated answer above, - You would need to extend JpaSpecificatinExecutor.

Comment: Child entity is still called even after:

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"id"},type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
Page<Parent> findAll(@Nullable Specification<Parent> spec, Pageable pageable);

Answer (score 0):

JPA provider usually takes fetch type Lazy as a hint,  so may be in your case its not considering it at all.  check below

> fetch public abstract FetchType fetch (Optional) Defines whether the
> value of the field or property should be lazily loaded or must be
> eagerly fetched. The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the
> persistence provider runtime that the value must be eagerly fetched.
> The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime. If
> not specified, defaults to EAGER. Default: EAGER

[JPA Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html#fetch%28%29)

Comment: Rather than pointing on whole documentation you can quote specific paragraph that made you think of such statement. However,  link on the whole docs should be left as refference.